# Show empty cells in a join clause

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I'm trying to make a table show it's full content eventhough there might be some empty cells. The table contains ten possible positions (i.e. chairman, secretary etc) in a small club. Each position refers to a member ID in a member table depending on who has been elected to said position. A position may be vacant and this is what I'm trying to accomplish. The structure (simplified) is as follows:
**Table "members"**

```
CREATE TABLE members (
    id_member INT NOT NULL,
    member_name VARCHAR(45),
    PRIMARY KEY (id_member));
```

**Table "positions"**

```
CREATE TABLE positions (
    id_position INT NOT NULL,
    position_name VARCHAR(45),
    PRIMARY KEY (id_position)
    FOREIGN KEY (id_member) REFERENCES members(id_member));
```

**Select syntax**

```
SELECT position_name, member_name
FROM members
JOIN positions USING(id_members);
```

It works very well as long as there is a member on a position but if it's vacant, that row doesn't appear. Is there some way to make the table positions always return every row eventhough the column id_member has empty cells?
Desired result:
Chariman - Jack Carver
Secretary - Joe Hill
Accounter - NULL
Webmaster - Joanna Robson

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `LEFT JOIN` instead and interchange the tableNames

```
SELECT position_name, member_name
FROM   positions
       LEFT JOIN members USING(id_members);
```

To fully gain knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Comment: if he uses left join I think you should have members and positions reversed to get the output he's asking for

Comment: @PaoloFalabella yep, i updated it before you posted this comment. the reason why i missed it is because of *copy-paste* thingy.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT position_name, member_name
FROM members
LEFT JOIN positions
ON members.id_member = positions.id_member;
```